# java.io.FileNotFoundException, mkdir not working properly?

Tags: java, android

I am getting this error, as if the directory was not being found. I had this code working before
and I simply just changed the path where I want to be created the file.
My app also has all the needed priviledge, as stated, it worked perfectly.

Before is was:

```
String path = STORAGE_PATH + "/DCMI" + "/Appdnp";
```

I simply changed to:

```
String path = STORAGE_PATH + "/.vilarica" + "/Appdnp";
```

And it started giving me `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/.vilarica/Appdnp/5WmK6658f9eKcp2h0QghGToCKOi2.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

I also tried changing the folder names, nothing worked,also making the first folder not hidden,etc.
I searched all around, found many resolutions of wrong paths, wrong names etc, but since it was working before I can't really see how that helps me here.

Storage path is:

```
public static final String STORAGE_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
```

But I don't think it's this since it was working before, and it gets the path correctly.
This is the part of the code from the class that represents these methods:

```
 private Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String path = STORAGE_PATH + "/.vilarica" + "/Appdnp";

                    writeFile(path, data);
                }
            }, "captureThread").start();
            startPreview();
        }
    };

    public void writeFile(String path, byte[] data) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if (data != null){
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        }

        if (bitmap != null){
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if (mCameraId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                matrix.postRotate(90);
            }else if (mCameraId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT){
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                matrix.postScale(1, -1);
            }
            Bitmap rotateBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),
                    bitmap.getHeight(), matrix,false);
            saveBmp2SD(path, rotateBmp);
            rotateBmp.recycle();
        }
    }

    private void saveBmp2SD(String path, Bitmap bitmap){
        File file = new File(path);
        if (!file.exists()){
            file.mkdir();
        }
        String uid = user.getUid();
        //String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String fileName = path + "/" + uid + ".jpg";
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
            Log.i("TAG", "Take picture success!");
            Intent i = new Intent(this, DPCalc.class);
            i.putExtra("filename", fileName);
            i.putExtra("path", path);
            startActivity(i);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("TAG", "The save file for take picture does not exists!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("TAG", "Take picture fail!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You only changed one directory but now you are on Android Q.

Comment: `if (!file.exists()){
            file.mkdir();
        }` Change to: `if (!file.exists()){
            if(!file.mkdirs()){   Toast(...could not make directory ..); return; }
        }`. You will see that toast i bet.

Answer (score 0):

.mkdir() only makes one directory, AND if it fails, you don't get an exception, it returns 'false'. Real java has a proper API but I don't think android gets the benefit of this nicer API, it's too far behind on libraries. So:

1. Don't call file.mkdir(); it's file.getParent().mkdirs().
2. Check the return value of mkdirs().
3. Note that 'false' on mkdirs() means either that the dir is already there and nothing was done, or that the operation failed; it is not possible to determine why it failed.

I mentioned this API sucks, right? I guess... you could in theory write your own mkdirs which walks up the tree 'manually'. Alternatively, use if (!path.isDirectory()) to check if it already exists, and fail (without being capable of telling the user why) if .mkdirs() returns false.

Comment: To check the return of mkdirs, they return a boolean then, but making my own API seems a too far of a stretch to me =D. Will test this out and see what I get, just any idea why it worked before?

Comment: Tried using getParent(), but like that it didn't compile, instead I hardcoded the path as `File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/.vilarica" + "/Appdnp");` and surprise, it works. I will go on logging not around the app to see what was not being sent correctly...

Comment: Okay, that sounds like: [1] the .vilarica directory already exists (if it did not, the mkdirs() would be mandatory, as you'd need to be making 2 dirs). [2] The Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() call was returning e.g. "/foo/bar/", note the ending slash. new File("/hello/", "/world") makes "/hello/world". concatenating the string makes "/hello//world" which is different. Possibly interpreted as either a broken path, or as "/world", which doesn't exist / you can't mkdirs, as you don't have the admin rights.